# Why did cooper communicate using morse code, when he could have directly written the numbers using sand

Tags: interstellar

In the scene where Cooper sends NASA coordinates using Morse code with the help of sand. Why did he use Morse code specifically, why didn't he write the numbers directly?

Also if he can push and push things in the earth from the tesseract, he could have easily grabbed a book, wrote in it and then deliver the same through the library!

Sorry if you think questions are silly but i have trouble understanding how exactly the communication using gravity worked.

Comment: I don't think it was the numbers that he was trying to communicate. It was some sort of data, equation.

Comment: There is a part where he is sending coordinates of NASA after the standstorm scene

Comment: I thought you were talking about Cooper sending data to his daughter. That was different scenario.

Comment: Because only gravitational waves can be sent, as explained here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27593/13595 Also, how do you go from "he can push and push things in the earth from the tesseract" to "he could have easily grabbed a book, wrote in it"? Those are wildly different things. Just because I can push a car doesn't mean I can drive it.

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for the link but that still does not explains how he was able to use gravity to manipulate or make a change in the earth

Comment: Written in the book with what?  The control required to take a book, open it, take a pen from the room, and manipulate that with gravity to write in the book was clearly harder than using gravity to manipulate dust in the room to drop in a binary on/off pattern.

Comment: "that still does not explain how he was able to use gravity" ... the idea is that the future human race created the Tesseract (the area that Coop is exploring) as a tool to project Coop into his past using gravity.

Comment: Okay but how do you use gravity to exactly alter the sand, I mean how exactly you increase/decrease gravity to make a movement in earth? I mean as I understand gravity it's a force exerted by one object to another due to it's mass.

Comment: We're just meant to assume "advanced technology beyond our understanding".  The descendents of the human race can create wormholes, they can use the same manipulation to move dust in a room.

Comment: So is your question "why does he use binary rather than writing numbers in decimal with the dust" (which is what the title shows), or is it about "how does sending a message with gravity actually work" which is what you are asking now? Because I'm kind for formulating answers to these, but they are different questions.

Comment: Sorry i know I am not allowed to ask multiple question but yes my original question is what is stated in the question, using gravity to alter sand was just a follow up. Please ignore that question and please post the answer. I would love to go through it.

Comment: He can use ***gravitational waves*** which is not the same as ***gravity***.

Comment: @BCdotWEB in the entire movie, they nowhere have mentioned anything about gravitational waves though!

Answer (score 4):

### Why morse code rather than roman letters?

Morse, being a binary encoding, dots-and-dashes, is one dimensional and requires less manipulation to create than two dimensional roman letters.  We see Coop reach out with his arms to effectively block the dust falling, creating the morse code stripes. Those movements are somehow translated by the tesseract into a gravity anomaly that blocks the dust in the past.

It's hard to see how Coop could create two dimensional letters like this (without more tools or ways of creating a template of the message he wants to send).

Comment: okay so you are saying that he can touch the sand that are going inside the room, but cannot himself appear in person inside the room and communicate the same?

Comment: @Himanshuman it appears his interactions with the room is limited.